# The result from mysql_fetch_assoc() compounds old values onto new values. Any ideas?

Tags: php, mysql

I'll start with the problem. I'm looping through mysql_fetch_assoc() calls to display all fields from a row. Every new pass gives me the new row PLUS the old row values as well. It compounds each pass. I've tried many things and looked through many posts and forums and haven't quite found what I need to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

edit: Sorry but the indentation gets messed up after I post the question.

Here's the MySQL table script:

```
CREATE TABLE pay_hours
(
    _key        int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    _userNumber     int(11),
    _hoursWorked    double
);

CREATE TABLE pay_dates
(
    _key        int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    _userNumber int(11),
    _dateWorked date    
);
```

Here's the query:

```
$query = "SELECT h._userNumber, d._dateWorked, h._hoursWorked FROM pay_hours h, pay_dates d WHERE d._userNumber=h._userNumber ORDER BY d._dateWorked DESC";  // gets the user, hours and dates and displys most recent dates first.

$result = $keyFrameObject->Execute($query);  // wrapper for mysql_query()
```

Here's the loop:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

while ($row)
{
    $table .= "<tr>";

    foreach ($row as $field)
    {
        $table .= "<td>" . $field . "</td>";
    }

    $table .= "</tr>";
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

It's a PHP page and I will eventually echo a table created with this data. I'm entering values for dateWorked and hoursWorked while using the same userNumber value for testing purposes. Here's some sample input and output (using `var_dump($row)` ):

input:

```
date = 2011-08-05
hours = 1
```

output:

```
array(3) { ["_userNumber"]=> string(3) "333" ["_dateWorked"]=> string(10) "2011-08-05" ["_hoursWorked"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Now the page has posted back and I'll enter in a new set of values:

input:

```
date = 2011-08-04
hours = 5
```

output (unformatted):

```
array(3) { ["_userNumber"]=> string(3) "333" ["_dateWorked"]=> string(10) "2011-08-05" ["_hoursWorked"]=> string(1) "5" } array(3) { ["_userNumber"]=> string(3) "333" ["_dateWorked"]=> string(10) "2011-08-05" ["_hoursWorked"]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { ["_userNumber"]=> string(3) "333" ["_dateWorked"]=> string(10) "2011-08-04" ["_hoursWorked"]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { ["_userNumber"]=> string(3) "333" ["_dateWorked"]=> string(10) "2011-08-04" ["_hoursWorked"]=> string(1) "5" }
```

output (formatted):

```
array(3) { ["_userNumber"]=> string(3) "333" ["_dateWorked"]=> string(10) "2011-08-05" ["_hoursWorked"]=> string(1) "5" } 

array(3) { ["_userNumber"]=> string(3) "333" ["_dateWorked"]=> string(10) "2011-08-05" ["_hoursWorked"]=> string(1) "1" } 

array(3) { ["_userNumber"]=> string(3) "333" ["_dateWorked"]=> string(10) "2011-08-04" ["_hoursWorked"]=> string(1) "1" } 

array(3) { ["_userNumber"]=> string(3) "333" ["_dateWorked"]=> string(10) "2011-08-04" ["_hoursWorked"]=> string(1) "5" }
```

Every time I enter in values and run through the code, it compounds further. I believe the issue is the loop but I'm not sure. Somehow $row is maintaining value after a post back.

Thanks again for the help and let me know if any more info is needed.

Comment: Where are you doing the var_ dump? If it is inside the while loop then the output you show is what would be expected. What does var_dump($table) show after the while loop completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The answer is in the comments below. Thanks for the help.

> I've figured it out. Because of the design of the tables, it would insert twice which would cause compounding. I changed everything into a single table and the ambiguity disappeared. Thanks for all of your help. I'm not sure how to mark this as solved, but if the mods are watching, could you help a brother out? – Matt 9 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

Change $table .= ""; to $table = "";

The .= is preserving the values of $table from the previous loops.

Comment: @matt, no problem. Please remember to accept answers and vote. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would help but it hasn't. the " .= " has to be there because it's appended onto "<table>" and followed by "</table>. Then:   echo $table;

Comment: After looking more, I've noticed it adds to the database twice. I don't know why as the addition isn't in a loop. I'll post if I find my own solution but feel free to add more. Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: I'd normally be a bit more proactive with my help, but I'm travelling and working on my iPad which is a bit of a pain. If you have no solution by the time I get home I'll look into it a bit more.

Comment: I've figured it out. Because of the design of the tables, it would insert twice which would cause compounding. I changed everything into a single table and the ambiguity disappeared. Thanks for all of your help. I'm not sure how to mark this as solved, but if the mods are watching, could you help a brother out?